# How to execute test dll which created on MSTest v 11.0 on a MSTest v 14.0

Tags: c#, mstest

> Microsoft (R) Test Execution Command Line Tool Version 14.0.23107.0
>   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
>
> Loading AdminPortal.dll... AdminXXXXX.dll Could not load file or
>   assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.CodedUITest Framework,
>   Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' o
>   r one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

I got this message when trying to run a test dll which was created on MStest V 11.0
and I'm trying to run this on MSTest V14.0

How do I resolve this without installing MSTest v 11.0?

Answer (score 1):

**If you can open the test in Visual Studio v14.0**

Open the test solution and change the reference to the CodedUITestFramework. It should show as a broken reference because you don't have v11.0 installed. Then save and recompile.

**If you can't open the test in VS 14.0**

Your best option (which may not work) is to edit the test's app.config to include the following:

```
<dependentAssembly>  
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.CodedUITestFramework"  
      publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a"  
      culture="neutral" />  

    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="11.0.0.0" newVersion="14.0.0.0" />  
  </dependentAssembly>
```

If possible, you're better off recompiling with the new version, because there may be changes that will impact the behavior of your test. It's also possible that the reference to the dependency is tied to the path of a specific Visual Studio version, which will also make a recompile necessary.